# Chrome extension : how to check whether proxy set using pac script is working or not

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy

This is how I have set the proxy using **chrome proxy api**  :

```
  const pacScriptConfig = {
    mode: 'pac_script',
    pacScript: {
      data: `function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
        if (host === "google.com") {
          return "PROXY 117.242.147.89:57599";
        } else {
          return "DIRECT";
        }
      }`
    }
  };

chrome.proxy.settings.set(
      { value: pacScriptConfig, scope: 'regular' }, () => {});
```

- And from what i investigated the we can debug proxies by generating **netlog file** under **chrome://net-export**. Below is the netlog file output for the url I am trying to set the proxy but I really can't understand anything from it. Are there any docs around to understand the output of the netlog file. ( I couldn't find one! )
- **Basically, How to know whether the proxy we have set for a particular domain using pac script is working or not. Are there any other tools to figure this out, something like network sniffer which can help with this information ?**

Any help / suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

**Netlog file output** :

```
t=4497 [st=0] +HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER  [dt=2]
               --> is_preconnect = true
               --> url = "https://www.google.com/"
t=4497 [st=0]   +PROXY_RESOLUTION_SERVICE  [dt=2]
t=4499 [st=2]      PROXY_RESOLUTION_SERVICE_RESOLVED_PROXY_LIST
                   --> pac_string = "DIRECT"
t=4499 [st=2]   -PROXY_RESOLUTION_SERVICE
t=4499 [st=2]    HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_PROXY_SERVER_RESOLVED
                 --> proxy_server = "DIRECT"
t=4499 [st=2]    HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_STARTED_JOB
                 --> source_dependency = 17290 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=4499 [st=2] -HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER
```

Comment: The net log says Chrome chose `DIRECT` route, not `PROXY`, because `host` is `www.google.com`, not `google.com`.

Comment: @wOxxOm, how did you infer this. In netlog file, its mentioned url and not host. Host is google.com only.

Comment: No, per RFC specs, host is `www.google.com`.

Comment: @wOxxOm, let me try it with www.google.com in the pacScript config then.

Comment: BTW you can use [dnsDomainIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_(PAC)_file#dnsDomainIs(host,%20domain)) function e.g. if (dnsDomainIs(host, '.google.com'))

Comment: @wOxxOm, dnsDomainIs worked! Thanks a lot.